# apidocjs not returning anything in response

Tags: documentation, documentation-generation, code-documentation, api-doc

I have installed 'apidoc' after installing 'npm' and 'node' for my API documentation by the help of following command:

```
npm install apidoc -g
```

After installing apidoc globally, I simply ran below command on my project directory (assuming apidoc will consider its default template file):

```
apidoc
```

In result no errors and no documentation generated.

Similarly, I have tried:

```
apidoc -i ~/PROJECTS/jruby/project/webservice/ -o ~/PROJECTS/apidocs/apidoc/ -t ~/PROJECTS/apidocs/mytemplate/
```

But nothing happens, in that case I had nothing on 'mytemplate' directory.

Can you guys please tell me what I've missed to install/consider? and why nothing is appearing on command execution?

**Note:** I'm using this for my ruby application, but unable to install its gem as we're running our application on ruby 1.9 and it requires ruby 2.0. I need an independent solution that should works for other projects as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution; copied 'package.json' file from https://github.com/apidoc/apidoc and ran below command for npm

```
npm install
```

after getting success install nodejs properly by following steps:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -

sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

then went to the project directory and ran the following command:

```
apidoc
```

after success of above command got html document in doc/ directory inside project. Cheers !